# Model Plugin does not load

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey guys,

I am trying to do the following:

run a world with a world plugin -> world plugin creates a model (also with plugin).
If I create a sensor with a sensor plugin (dynamically with the world plugin) then the sensor plugin is loaded. The model plugin is not...

I tried multiple versions of gazebo (1.4, 1.6, 1.9). Can you give me a hint?

Here are some code snippets:
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/v6jLbsaa)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3702/model-plugin-does-not-load/) by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-07-22**:
Does it give any hint why? error / warning msg? I used to do this as well and I think it worked.

**Comment by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on 2013-07-22**:
First very embarrassing error: I forgot to set the plugin path for the model plugin lib... but this is not the solution.... I will upload some more code and the output (there are no error / warning msg -> its just not loaded)

**Comment by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on 2013-07-22**:
Second error: after the _parent->InsertModelSDF(sphereSDF); in the load method of the world-plugin there was a " node->WaitForConnection();" that waited for a message from the model plugin.... very stupid errors... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like @Chris answered his own question in the comments.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on 2013-07-24**:
Sorry, I don't know how to close a thread....